# htop - change units for memory usage display

Tags: linux, memory, htop

[How to display meminfo in megabytes in top?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105908/how-to-display-meminfo-in-megabytes-in-top/105933#105933) discusses how to change the units of memory (e.g. megabytes, gigabytes, etc.) when using `top`.  Is there a way to do this in `htop` as well?  `man htop` doesn't address this, neither does it seem evident from the info displayed via `F1` when running the program.

Alternatively, if there were at least a way to change the threshold at which `htop` automatically switches from one unit to another, that would work.  E.g. right now, it will display memory in terms of `4406M` which I find quite difficult to read at a glance in a long line of processes.  So, if I could just get it to not go above hundreds of units, and thus automatically switch this to, e.g. `4.4G`, when it goes above `999M` then that would work too.

Comment: For those wondering what the units are in htop when there is no `M`/`G` suffix (just a plain number) the default is KiB though this is not documented (see https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/1340)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, but, if you are up for building your own htop, not impossible.  The code is at [github](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop) and if you look at Meter.c you will see the logic they use to decide what to display.

Comment: but why not? isnt htop a kind of improved top?

Comment: Looks like it is in the works by the new htop team: https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/224