# Appearance of plus (+) in top output

Tags: top

This is the output of my top command.

```
Tasks: 633 total,   1 running, 380 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9.9 us,  1.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 65.1 id, 23.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 26407128+total,  1078396 free, 31198216 used, 23179465+buff/cache
KiB Swap: 26419200+total, 26342462+free,   767368 used. 23102633+avail Mem
```

What are the plus signs in memory representations - does it mean the system cannot estimate the whole available memory or the number is too long to write here? How do I show the whole memory?

Comment: To be able to answer as specifically as possible, could you please add what Unix (and variant/version/release) this is running under?

Comment: Related: [How to display meminfo in megabytes in top?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105908/how-to-display-meminfo-in-megabytes-in-top)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` means the number was too long to fit here.  You can see different representations of the number with the `E` command.

From the [top(1) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html):

> **E**  : *Extend-Memory-Scale* in Summary Area
>
> With this command you can cycle through the available summary area memory scaling  which  ranges  from
>                 KiB (kibibytes or 1,024 bytes) through EiB (exbibytes or 1,152,921,504,606,846,976 bytes).
>
> If  you  see a '+' between a displayed number and the following label, it means that top was forced to
>                 truncate some portion of that number.  By raising the scaling factor, such truncation can be avoided.